# Is getting the value of @Published property (without changing it) from the background thread is the right thing to do?

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency

To prevent misinterpreting the question: I am well aware that *publishing* new values for `@Published` property from the background thread is not allowed. **This is not my question though.**

**I want to know if *getting / reading* a value of `@Published` property from the background thread (without changing it) is OK**. And if not, why?

For example:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name: String = ""
    
    func saveName() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            print("Getting name from background: \(self.name)") // <-- HERE
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Name", text: $viewModel.name)
            Button("Submit") {
                viewModel.saveName()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Intuitively it feels wrong, but

- No compilation error
- No runtime error when running such code
- Didn't see any side effects, and
- Nothing specific in the docs saying this is wrong

So is this a valid code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked:

> So is this a valid code?

The code implicitly makes a number of claims that are inconsistent with thread-safety. Specifically:

- the property is mutable (i.e., it is a variable, not a constant) … the code is obviously not actually mutating it yet, but declaring it as a variable expresses that it represents a mutable state;
- this property is inside a type that offers no synchronization (i.e., it is not inside a “sendable” type); and
- the GCD dispatch expects anything that anything “captured” by its closure be thread-safe (i.e., the closure is decorated with `@Sendable`, telling the compiler to check whether anything captured by the closure is actually “sendable” or not; it must be immutable or synchronized).

The whole idea of thread-safety is to ensure that there cannot be unsynchronized mutation. It is an interesting academic question as to whether you want to call this example “invalid”: The code is technically not yet doing anything unsafe (i.e., there is no mutation) but it nonetheless represents an unsynchronized, mutable state. This can be fixed either by making the property immutable (a `let` constant) or by making the type that contains the property “sendable“.

You noted that you have not received a compilation error. That is because Apple has, by default, disabled much of the sendability checking (i.e., the detection of unsynchronized, mutable states). This will be enforced in Swift 6, but in 5.x, it is still an optional check. (This was a conscious decision to give us time to adopt these new patterns, to write code that the compiler could correctly validate for thread-safety.)

One can enable this detection of unsynchronized mutable states by setting the “Strict concurrency checking” build setting to “Complete”. If you do that, Xcode will warn you of the problem:

[image]

And if you make the `ObservableObject` sendable, by isolating it to the main actor (as advised in WWDC 2021’s video [Discover concurrency in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10019/?time=1290)), you will now get warnings about accessing `name`, now isolated to the main actor, from the background queue:

[image]

If you have a property being published to the UI, it is simplest to isolate the whole type with the `@Published` property to the main actor and eliminate the use of GCD. For example, let’s assume that you wanted to save the name, but because this might take more than a few milliseconds, you might move this off the main actor. You would just supply this actor-isolated property as a parameter to your function running on some other actor:

```swift
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = ""

    let databaseManager = DatabaseManagerOnOtherActor()

    func saveName() async throws {
       try await databaseManager.save(name)
    }

    func loadName() async throws {
       name = try await databaseManager.name()
    }
}

actor DatabaseManagerOnOtherActor {
    func save(_ name: String) throws { … }

    func name() throws -> String { … }
}
```

So, we avoid blocking the main thread, this is thread-safe, but no GCD is required (and, in fact, it generally should be avoided in conjunction with `async`-`await`).

Bottom line, your intuition that something was amiss is correct. The purpose of the compile-time checks is not to inform you that you actually have manifested a race, but rather, at the very least, to warn you that you are susceptible to one. The idea is that if we observe all the warnings, we will be free of low-level data races.

The WWDC 2022 video, [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/), is a good (if basic) primer on the topic.

Comment: Isn't it _technically_ safe for reading word-sized values, which the underlying platform guarantees will be mutated atomically? e.g. if the value is Int64, you won't observer 32 bits of an old value, and 32 bits of a new value. It'll be the full correct old value, or the full correct new value

Comment: Oh yeah, Strings are 2 words, so you're in for some real fun there! Same for all existential values, too (4 words). I guess it's just really easy to get wrong, and better to play safe (using explicit synchronization of some sort), even if it's ultimately unnecessary in (hard to identify) niche cases.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. It came up on code review, and I was missing objective proof to why such code is not a great idea...

Comment: Alexander, two observations. First, the CPU-level mutual exclusion on load/store does not ensure thread-safety, as CPU instructions are the wrong level of abstraction. We need to be able to reason about thread-safety at the function level (or at least at the level of continuations). Second, for non-trivial string lengths, `String` employs addition mutable heap storage, exceeding any exclusion that the CPU, alone, offers. We really need the sort of exclusion that Swift concurrency (or other legacy mechanism) offers.